# Reversing a vote to close

Tags: discussion, voting

Does anyone know how I might reverse a vote to close a discussion ?

Comment: never mind: it can't be done. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(You already know the answer, but let me post it as an answer.)

Unfortunately, we cannot cancel close votes at our own will.  See the [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) on Meta Stack Overflow and the [answer from Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949), one of the administrators of the Stack Exchange network.

This may not be actually as bad as it sounds, because close votes expire after some amount of time.  See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags/97581#97581) for detail.