# How to withdraw close votes?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reversing a vote to close](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/reversing-a-vote-to-close)

I was recently browsing the questions and by accident (I thought I was in a different tab) voted to close a question off-topic:

[Can quantum algorithms with exponential speed-up be rederived using span-programs?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/12319/1037)

In no way do I think this question is off-topic (and hopefully 4 others won't also accidentally vote), but I can't find a way to withdraw my close vote. Is there a mechanism in place to do so? I imagine accidental votes like mine don't happen often (since it requires 3 button clicks; and only the completely absent minded people like me would get confused by that), but questions do get edited for the better, potentially nullifying an early close-vote.

**How can I withdraw my close vote?**